# Creating dynamic dictionary from the key (given list_value)

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Example-1

```
f_list = ['az','bf','cw','ddft']
```

Expected output-1

```
dynamic_dict = {0:'az',1:'bf',2:'cw',3:'ddft'}
```

Example-2

```
f_list = ['av','bm']
```

Expected output-2

```
dynamic_dict = {0:'av',1:'bm'}
```

Here `f_list` can be of any length from 1 to any positive number , dictionary should be created accordingly.
Here the key would always be sequential number based on the length of list. `For Eg if length of list is 4 , then dictionary will have 4 keys from 0 to 3 and and the value will be from list it self`

Comment: Did you try using the dictionary's constructor that accepts tuples? `dict(enumerate(f_list))`

Comment: Do you really need such a dictionary? The original list is already indexed by the keys you assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict()`, when given a list of 2-tuples, will automatically assign the first element of each tuple as a key, and the second element as the corresponding value. The built-in `enumerate()` provides this automatically:

```
def produce_dict(lst):
    return dict(enumerate(lst))
```

```
>>> dict(enumerate(['az','bf','cw','ddft']))
{0: 'az', 1: 'bf', 2: 'cw', 3: 'ddft'}
>>> dict(enumerate(['av','bm'] ))
{0: 'av', 1: 'bm'}
```

Comment: Such a simple task does not need to be encapsulated into a function. I think the name `produce_dict` will make code harder to understand, not easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
dynamic_dict = {n:x for n,x in enumerate(f_list)}
```

Comment: `dict(enumerate(f_list))` is enough. No need to add comprehension.